# Splitting a K-length list into L sub-lists that are as "even" as possible, even if K/L leaves a remainder

Tags: python, list, math, division, sublist

I don't know of a better way to word what I'm looking for, so please bear with me.

Let's say that I have a list of 17 elements. For the sake of brevity we'll represent this list as `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ`. If I wanted to divide this into 7 sufficiently "even" sub-lists, it might look like this:

**`ABC` `DE` `FGH` `IJ` `KL` `MNO` `PQ`**

Here, the lengths of each sub-list are **3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2**. The maximum length is only one more than the minimum length: `ABC` `DE` `FGH` `I` `JKL` `MN` `OPQ` has seven sub-lists as well, but the range of lengths is two here.

Furthermore, examine how many 2's separate each pair of 3's: this follows the same rule of RANGE ≤ 1. The range of lengths in `ABC` `DEF` `GH` `IJ` `KLM` `NO` `PQ` is 1 as well, but they are imbalanced: 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2. Ideally, if one were to keep reducing the sub-list in such a fashion, the numbers would never deviate from one another by more than one.

Of course, there is more than one way to "evenly" divide a list into sub-lists in this fashion. I'm not looking for an exhaustive set of solutions - if I can get one solution in Python for a list of any length and any number of sub-lists, that's good enough for me. The problem is that I don't even know where to begin when solving such a problem. Does anyone know what I'm looking for?

Comment: Do the resulting sub-lists need to have distributed lengths?  I mean, using your example input, is `3,3,3,2,2,2,2` acceptable, or is `2,3,2,3,2,3,2` preferable, or is `3,2,3,2,2,3,2` the ideal case?

Comment: @g.d.d.c `2,3,2,3,2,3,2` and `3,2,3,2,2,3,2` are both sufficiently even - for my purposes, they're essentially the same sequence, because the latter is the former shifted 4 elements to the right. `3,3,3,2,2,2,2` would not be acceptable because the distance between each pair of threes would be `0,0,4` - definitely outside of the acceptable range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of length N, and you want some number of sub-lists S, it seems to me that you should start with a division with remainder.  For N == 17 and S == 7, you have 17 // 7 == 2 and 17 % 7 == 3.  So you can start with 7 length values of 2, but know that you need to increment 3 of the length values by 1 to handle the remainder.  Since your list of length values is length 7, and you have 3 values to increment, you could compute X = 7 / 3 and use that as a stride: increment the 0th item, then the int(X) item, the int(2*X) item, and so on.

If that doesn't work for you, I suggest you get a book called *The Algorithm Design Manual* by Skiena, and look through the set and tree algorithms.

http://www.algorist.com/

Comment: I tried this out with a couple of input numbers and it works exactly as I described it. Thank you for the explanation! I'll look into reading the book as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ'
>>> parts=7
>>> [s[i*len(s)//parts:(i+1)*len(s)//parts] for i in range(parts)]
['AB', 'CD', 'EFG', 'HI', 'JKL', 'MN', 'OPQ']


>>> import string
>>> for j in range(26):
...  print [string.uppercase[i*j//parts:(i+1)*j//parts] for i in range(parts)]
... 
['', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '', 'A']
['', '', '', 'A', '', '', 'B']
['', '', 'A', '', 'B', '', 'C']
['', 'A', '', 'B', '', 'C', 'D']
['', 'A', 'B', '', 'C', 'D', 'E']
['', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'GH']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'DE', 'F', 'G', 'HI']
['A', 'B', 'CD', 'E', 'FG', 'H', 'IJ']
['A', 'BC', 'D', 'EF', 'G', 'HI', 'JK']
['A', 'BC', 'DE', 'F', 'GH', 'IJ', 'KL']
['A', 'BC', 'DE', 'FG', 'HI', 'JK', 'LM']
['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH', 'IJ', 'KL', 'MN']
['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH', 'IJ', 'KL', 'MNO']
['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GHI', 'JK', 'LM', 'NOP']
['AB', 'CD', 'EFG', 'HI', 'JKL', 'MN', 'OPQ']
['AB', 'CDE', 'FG', 'HIJ', 'KL', 'MNO', 'PQR']
['AB', 'CDE', 'FGH', 'IJ', 'KLM', 'NOP', 'QRS']
['AB', 'CDE', 'FGH', 'IJK', 'LMN', 'OPQ', 'RST']
['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PQR', 'STU']
['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PQR', 'STUV']
['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKLM', 'NOP', 'QRS', 'TUVW']
['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHIJ', 'KLM', 'NOPQ', 'RST', 'UVWX']
['ABC', 'DEFG', 'HIJ', 'KLMN', 'OPQ', 'RSTU', 'VWXY']
```

Comment: Anyone know how to stop SO from thinking that `//` is the start of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

See the "grouper" example at http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html

Comment: The function that `grouper` provides actually does occur elsewhere in the program I'm writing, but it solves the remainder issue simply by padding the last sub-list, which isn't what I'm looking for in this question.